# How to find time-in and time-out from a single field and extract its value to another table in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin, field

I have 2 tables in PHP MyAdmin, first is `tb_data_log` that stores all information from data records. I need to find `time-in` and `time-out` from first table and then extract the value to second table that is `tb_attendance`. Look at image bellow:

**tb_data_log**

`uid    date        time
 1      28/01/2017  07.12
 1      28/01/2017  16.02
 2      28/01/2017  07.05
 2      28/01/2017  16.23
 3      28/01/2017  07.00
 3      28/01/2017  16.16
 1      29/01/2017  07.24
 1      29/01/2017  16.11
 2      29/01/2017  07.09
 2      29/01/2017  16.45
 3      29/01/2017  07.12
 3      29/01/2017  16.02
 1      30/01/2017  07.12
 1      30/01/2017  16.02
 2      30/01/2017  07.29
 2      30/01/2017  16.19
 3      30/01/2017  07.22
 3      30/01/2017  16.56`

I need my table to look like this bellow:

**tb_attendance**

`uid    date        time_in  time_out
 1      28/01/2017  07.12    16.02
 2      28/01/2017  07.05    16.23
 3      28/01/2017  07.00    16.16
 1      29/01/2017  07.24    16.11
 2      29/01/2017  07.09    16.45
 3      29/01/2017  07.12    16.02
 1      30/01/2017  07.12    16.02
 2      30/01/2017  07.29    16.19
 3      30/01/2017  07.22    16.56`

I think it is basically simple, but I have no idea how to write the codes in MySQL. How am I supposed to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Although one could write the code to achieve this. The practice is prone to a lot of errors. Multiple check-ins, check-outs can cause lot of error. You need to have a Check-in machine with Check-in/ Check-out button or two different machine to achieve perfection.

Comment: @AhyasWidyatmaka: Is it fixed that there will be only two entries for each user for each day, first one time_in and second one time_out ? Also share table structure of- `tb_data_log` table in your question.

Comment: @KeyurPanchal: No. Sometimes it has only one entry, sometimes two, sometimes it has more than two. That depends on how many times user input the data, and when they absence during the day, we have nothing to show.

tb_data_log structure:
uid: VARCHAR
date: VARCHAR
time: VARCHAR

Comment: @Oasa: I know, but unfortunately our machine has no such feature like so.

Comment: @AhyasWidyatmaka: If no. of entries is not fixed then how you want to make entries in tb_attendance? First entry as time_in and last entry as time_out ? And if sometimes only one entry, how ?

Answer (score 1):

This SQL should do the task:

```
INSERT INTO `tb_attendance` 
SELECT `uid`, 
       `date`, 
       Min(`time`) AS 'time_in', 
       Max(`time`) AS 'time_out' 
FROM   `tb_data_log` 
GROUP  BY `date`, 
          `uid`;
```

Provided that you have the following field types:

```
`uid`  INT, 
`date` DATE, 
`time` TIME
```

Comment: Wow, this is a brilliant way to solve all the complexities. +1. I was going to write the infamous cursor solution.

Comment: @JoeBlack: OMG! I think I've been thinking too much. Your solution is so simple. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AhyasWidyatmaka If you like this solution, then ACCEPT IT. People spend time to help others, and to not accept their answer, is considered rude.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into tb_attendance 
    select a.uid,
          a.date,
          a.time as 'time_in',
          (select b.time from tb_data_log b where a.uid = b.uid and b.time >      
          a.time and a.date = b.date limit 1) as 'time_out' 
    from tb_data_log a group by a.uid,a.date order by a.date,a.uid;
```